# How do I write this code about weekdays in R?

Tags: r

I have just started learning R, and was asked by my tutor to 'Write R code that prints a message:

> 'Today is Friday. Yesterday was Thursday. Tomorrow will be Saturday.' and works correctly on any day. Functions `paste()` and `weekdays()` may be useful.

If anyone would be happy to provide me with a code and/or some explaining behind it, as I'm stuck.

Thank you.

I'm not sure where to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Sys.Date()` returns the actual date when uses. Can be used to get the
today dates.

```r
today <- Sys.Date()
```

With today date you can get tomorrow and yesterday dates, adding and removing 1

```r
yesterday <- today - 1
tomorrow <- today + 1
  
paste0(
  'Today is ', weekdays(today),
  '. Yesterday was ', weekdays(yesterday),
  '. Tomorrow will be ', weekdays(tomorrow)
)
#> [1] "Today is Friday . Yesterday was Thursday . Tomorrow will be Saturday"
```

You can create a function to do this. I would use the glue package.

```r
print_message <- function() {
  today <- Sys.Date()
  yesterday <- today - 1
  tomorrow <- today + 1
  
  glue::glue("Today is {weekdays(today)}. Yesterday was {weekdays(yesterday)}. Tomorrow will be {weekdays(tomorrow)}")
}

print_message()
#> Today is Friday. Yesterday was Thursday. Tomorrow will be Saturday
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You may consider changing your first option to `paste0('Today is ', weekdays(Sys.Date()), '. Yesterday was ', weekdays(Sys.Date() - 1), '. Tomorrow will be ', weekdays(Sys.Date() + 1), ".")` so that it prints with proper spacing.